# How to print combined words on terminal?

Tags: printing, terminal, zsh

From PHOTO(By on my zsh):

I wonder how to print combined word on terminal? it looks so cool.
Is there any tool to do this.

Anyone knows? THX

[image: Words in Red Frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Have a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16837/what-are-some-good-ascii-art-generators), might give you an idea how it works and how you come up with images/graphics like that.

After you know what you want to print, you can simply output it like any other string.